# Keyboard starts as English even being configured for Spanish

Tags: keyboard-layout

Upon Ubuntu's installation I configured the keyboard to be Spanish.  I think it worked fine for a while but after sometime, and maybe some updates, every time I start Ubuntu it is set to English even though it shows as Spanish at the task-bar.  Once I click on the already ES-Spanish option, it works as it should be.

```
cat /etc/default/keyboard 

XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="es"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS=""
```

Please let me know what could I check.

Answer (score 0):

You could try checking the Keyboard Layout Chart to make sure that the key configuration matches up with your physical keyboard. Or, if your physical keyboard isn't a spanish keyboard, you can change the settings to English (International) which will still allow you to type accented characters.

Comment: Thanks.  The KB Chart shows it as Spanish (physical KB is Spanish).  Everything looks right, but it always starts as English.  I deleted the EN option, restarted and still the same issue.   I do not know where to check.  The only ref to the keyboard in dmesg is "input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input2"

Comment: @HectorVerdejo Do your Spanish keys not work when you try to type them? Or what exactly do you mean when you say that the keyboard is in English?

Comment: Everthing works, but with a different layout.  One example would be:

I start the computer, want to run my logs and open a terminal where I type "tailf &var&log&syslog" (shift 7 should be /) so I go to the task bar, clink on the ALREADY "ES" icon and now I can start using the Spanish layout.  It is not so bad, but I wish it would be persistent after reboots.